# Question about Nyx connections tab

Tags: nyx

I've just set up my first Tor node in my home (non-exit) and it seems to be working great, no issues setting it up. It was actually really easy which is awesome.

I have a question about one piece of info shown on the Nyx connections tab though.

The second to last column of every connection shows a number like `2.1m`, `+34.2m`, or `14.4m`. I first thought it was the connection time but new ones seem to pop onto the list with numbers higher than 0/1 so I don't think it's that, and not sure what the + would mean in that case either.

Could someone shed some light on it. The Nyx website doesn't really offer any descriptions about the information it displays.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Nyx so I have no idea if I'm right here, but it appears as if those show how long the connection has been alive. Here the 'm' shows minutes and the '+' identifies legacy connections (connections that have been alive longer than Nyx). See [`_draw_right_column()`](https://github.com/torproject/nyx/blob/796089d28debb1c4f6d4ee645214e3fc61068a12/nyx/panel/connection.py#L740-L741).

Comment: Thank you @Steve. I had convinced myself it couldn't be time, but it appears it must be. Thanks :D